# Cassandra where clause as a tuple

Tags: cassandra, cql

```
      Table12
CustomerId   CampaignID
  1              1
  1              2
  2              3
  1              3
  4              2                   
  4              4
  5              5
```

```
val CustomerToCampaign = ((1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(4,2),(4,4),(5,5))
```

Is it possible to write a query like

```
select CustomerId, CampaignID  from Table12 where (CustomerId, CampaignID) in (CustomerToCampaign_1, CustomerToCampaign_2)
```

???

So the input is a tuple but the columns are not tuple but rather individual columns.

Comment: Have you tried it?  What were the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.  But only on the clustering keys.  That means I need to use something else as a partition key or "bucket."  For this example, I'll assume that marketing campaigns are time sensitive and that we'll get a good distribution and easy of querying by using "month" as the bucket (partition).

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.customertocampaign (
    campaign_month int,
    customer_id int,
    campaign_id int,
    customer_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (campaign_month, customer_id, campaign_id)
);
```

Now, I can `INSERT` the data described in your `CustomerToCampaign` variable.  Then, this query works:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT campaign_month, customer_id, campaign_id
                             FROM customertocampaign WHERE campaign_month=202004 
                             AND (customer_id,campaign_id) = (1,2);

 campaign_month | customer_id | campaign_id
----------------+-------------+-------------
         202004 |           1 |           2

(1 rows)
```

Comment: wow didn't know that; also `SELECT * FROM customertocampaign WHERE campaign_month=202004 AND (customer_id, campaign_id) in ((1,1), (2,2))` that. Is there any drawback? Or just a syntactic sugar for multiple and/or conditions ?

Comment: @Ersoy Yes, that works, too.  As long as you specify a partition key `campaign_month` then `IN` only has to pull data from within that partition.  Otherwise it becomes a multi-key query, which will almost always be slow from hitting multiple nodes.